# VLOOKUP if Client ID is customer during the same month during different years

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a list containing four columns: Client ID, Year, Month, Recurring customer.

Each transaction during a month creates a row. I want to see if the same Client ID has a transaction on the same month in both yr. 2017 & yr. 2018. If yes, I want the fourth row to say "Yes", if not "No".

Example, the way I want it to act:

[image]

I'm using =IF(VLOOKUP(F892;'1'!$J$3:$L$1500;3;0)=2;"Yes";"No") in the fourth column, but all I get is Yes in the fourth column.

Any ideas to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part here is to make sure you aren't returning Yes for the two rows in the same month in the same year (i.e. 2017,8).

You can do this with COUNTIFS:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$12,$C2,$B$2:$B$12,"<>"&$B2)>0,"Yes","No")
```

In other words, if the count of rows in the range whose month is the same as the month on this row and whose year is *not* the same as the year on this row is greater than zero, then return Yes, otherwise return No.

[image]